# FNF Psych Engine Slow Down (Friday Night Funkin') lime test windows

Tags: lua, haxe, haxeflixel, haxelib, lime-haxe

(Sorry if there is typo I type this in a hurry)

> EDIT: The problem is gone for me but I have no idea why. I rebooted my pc many times and fail for days but somehow it goes back to normal now. I will leave this as unsolved for people who may run into same problem in the future

**2nd EDIT : IT DOESN'T WORK AGAIN**

### I am making a fnf mod so I compile the game and downloaded psych engine.

(in case anyone doesn't know here's the link https://github.com/ShadowMario/FNF-PsychEngine)

I run into an unexpected problem that I can't find anyone online has mentioned before. Maybe someone asked it but I can't find it after hours of searching. When I use the `lime test windows` command in powershell, the game runs but in a weird way. The FPS is stuck under 30 with red text and the game feels like slow down for 0.25x speed. I am pretty sure it is not lag as it goes smoothly but the animation of everything including ui and in game stuff is slow down. For example the black screen transitioning between menus just descends slowly on the screen for about 5 seconds until it fully covers up the entire screen. I have checked everything I make sure I compile it correctly and follow every instruction I can find on the web.

I run the game on my other pc with exact same files and it works just fine. A thing that I think may cause this issue is the pc with issues was updated to windows 11 while the one with no problem is still on windows 10. I am not sure if this matters but I can only think of this possible cause of the weirdness.

Anyone can tell me would I possibly missed something? Here's all the command I type when compiling:

```
haxelib install lime 7.9.0
haxelib install openfl
haxelib install flixel
haxelib run lime setup flixel
haxelib run lime setup
haxelib install flixel-tools
haxelib run flixel-tools setup
haxelib update flixel
haxelib install flixel-ui
haxelib install hscript
haxelib install flixel-addons
haxelib install actuate
haxelib run flixel-tools setup

haxelib git linc_luajit https://github.com/AndreiRudenko/linc_luajit
haxelib git hxvm-luajit https://github.com/nebulazorua/hxvm-luajit
haxelib git faxe https://github.com/uhrobots/faxe
haxelib git polymod https://github.com/MasterEric/polymod.git
haxelib git discord_rpc https://github.com/Aidan63/linc_discord-rpc
```

Also am I required to input this?

```
haxelib git extension-webm https://github.com/KadeDev/extension-webm
lime rebuild extension-webm windows
```

Update: After testing bunch of times, I found that the problem would be gone when I play any song. After that the game works normally, but still stuck at 30 fps(the cap is 240). When I reboot the game the same thing happens again and can only be solved with the same method. Anyone can help me prevent this happen every time the game is booted up?

Please Help

Answer (score 0):

can you try running psych engine on the pc you are using to compile?

Comment: what do you mean by that? In case you missed it in my long question, I try to run the engine on the pc I am using and the game runs in a slow down weirdness. It is not lag but gui and stuff are slowed for about 0.25x speed.

Comment: I tried it again and it works fine. I rebooted the pc so many time and retry for days but it won't work. Now it is normal but I have no idea why it got solved. Thanks for trying to help though.

Comment: well never mind a few hours later it has the same problem, again.

Answer (score 0):

#### I've found a solution to the problem recently.

**Do you have GeForce Experience?** If yes, check your settings, as mine is on 30FPS when my laptop isn't on charge. If no, check any other gaming software (if any) to see if that limits your FPS.

The reason it slows down I think is that **HaxeFlixel games aren't exactly designed to have other applications limiting FPS.**

Not quite sure about PCs as I haven't actually used one, but it could be limited when power consumption isn't above the threshold.

I apologize if this solution isn't applicable for you.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32100791)